# Replace tag if corresponding value not empty, otherwise don't show

Tags: php, replace

I have a code:

```
$html = '<html>
            <body>
                <p><a href="[LINK]">[LINK]</a></p>
                <p><img src="[IMAGE]" alt="something" /></p>
                <p>Language specific string: [ANOTHER TAG]</p>
            </body>
         </html>';
$search = array('[LINK]', '[IMAGE]');
$replace = array($post['link'], $post['image']);
$html = str_replace($search, $replace, $html);
```

Above will replace `[LINK]` and `[IMAGE]` with corresponding `$post` values - this is good when both values are not empty. I need a way to hide the corresponding paragraph when one or more `$post` values are empty. Anyone has an idea what would be the most efficient solution?
`$html` content is loaded using `file_get_contents` (the above is just an ilustration of its content).

**EDIT**: Since in the `$html` I also have "localized" strings, I'd rather use the solution that doesn't force me to replace the whole paragraph. There was a good answer that used DOM manipulation but the author has deleted it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html = '<html>
            <body>
                [LINK]
                [IMAGE]
            </body>
         </html>';
$search = array('[LINK]', '[IMAGE]');
$replace = array(
  (!empty($post['link'])) ? "<p><a href=\"{$post['link']}\">{$post['link']}</a></p>" : '', 
  (!empty($post['image'])) ? "<p><img src=\"{$post['image']}\" alt=\"something\" /></p>" : ''
);
$html = str_replace($search, $replace, $html);
```

Now `[LINK]` and `[IMAGE]` are replace with the whole tag if they are present, and an empty string if not.

Depending on how you generate the `$post` array, you may need to use some condition other than `empty()` to determine whether they are present, but you get the idea.

**EDIT**

Since these appear to be email template files, I would suggest using the templating functionality of PHP and put some PHP code inside the templates.

*Template file*

```
<html>
  <body>
<?php if (!empty($post['link'])) { ?>
    <p><a href="<?php echo $post['link']; ?>"><?php echo $post['link']; ?></a></p>
<?php } if (!empty($post['image'])) { ?>
    <p><img src="<?php echo $post['image']; ?>" alt="something" /></p>
<?php } if (!empty($post['another_tag'])) { ?>
    <p>Language specific string: <?php echo $post['another_tag']; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

*PHP script*

```
ob_start();
include('template.html');
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather use a solution that doesn't replace the whole <p> - see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if (empty($post['link']) || empty($post['image'])) {
    $html = str_replace('<p><a href="[LINK]">[LINK]</a></p>', '', $html);
    $html = str_replace('<p><img src="[IMAGE]" alt="something" /></p>', '', $html);
}
```

Comment: There is *still* no such function as `is_empty()`. It is amazing how many people here think there is... Also this does not deal with putting the correct content in if they are present.

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather use a solution that doesn't replace the whole <p> - see my updated question